# Miss Sizes Of Rows On Addition Of A Controls To Listview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview

The Listview is Databound by Sql Table  and  am trying to add controls like textbox on Listview as below:

```
listviewBinding();
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.BackColor = Color.Red;
tb.Text = "To Balance B/f";
tb.Width = listView1.Width;
listView1.Controls.Add(tb);
listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
```

The problem is that the top row is miss sizes and hence we can’t able to read it properly. What is the solution for it?.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a TextBox to a **ListView**? List views aren't *really* good container controls.

Comment: Christopher Pfohl, Do You have any better suggestion for this problem, I mean I want to set textbox on top of controls with some value or data bound and rest of rows of main controls will readable only.and it should be clickable controls

Comment: I'd write a custom control if I were you, then you can combine the list view with the text box, but you won't be trying to deal with laying them out on top of each other.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl, Do you have any sample or example

Comment: It's almost identical to programming a Form. You can drag/drop and handle events the exact same way, but instead you're building a re-usable control that can be placed *on* forms and container controls.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207.aspx

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl, So you wants to say that with the compisite controls and inheritance the same will solve the above problem am I right?.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11581/discussion-between-mahesh-and-christopher-pfohl)